# How to download source Code with bazaar?

Tags: version-control, bazaar, bugzilla

I want to upgrade my bugzilla 3.6.3 to 4.2. For downloading latest source I need bzr repository. When I tried to download the source on my company computer from bazaar repository, I got the following error messages.

```
C:/bugzilla/trunk
bzr: ERROR: unknown command "bzr co bzr://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla"
```

then I changed the bzr:// to http:// but still get the following error message:

```
Run command: bzr "bzr co http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla" 
C:/bugzilla/trunk 
bzr: ERROR: unknown command "bzr co http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla"
```

Maybe I need a proxy client for bzr but I can't find any proxy client for bazaar and I am not sure either.

I would appreciate if anybody can help in this regard.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

Did you run:

```
bzr "bzr co http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla"
```

?

you should run:

```
bzr co http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla
```

---

**Update**:
I just checked it out with

```
bzr co http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla
```

and it worked fine.

The "unknown command" error is because you double quoted it like that. The first word after `bzr` is the command in this case `co` which is short for checkout. So if you quote a whole bunch of things it is considered one word and obviously an invalid bzr command.  If doing it unquoted and it does not work, give us your exact command and the error please.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. I follow this link: [link](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Bzr)

Comment: @AmanicaA: thanks. here is the exact command bzr co http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla
-------------------------
and here is Error: Run command: bzr branch "bzr co http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla" "C:/trunk bugzilla" --use-existing-dir
bzr: ERROR: Unsupported protocol for url "bzr co http://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla"

Comment: That command is wrong, you should either use "bzr branch SOURCE DESTINATION"  or "bzr co SOURCE BRANCH", not specify one as argument to the other.

Comment: You are still not giving us the correct command. The command you are running is `bzr branch "bzr co bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla" "C:/trunk bugzilla" --use-existing-dir`, but it should be exactly as I have given it in my answer with nothing before or after it and with no quotes. I suggest that you give us a screenshot so we can see exactly what you are doing wrong (you can paste it somewhere like here: http://snag.gy/ )

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a bzr GUI tool like qbzr or bzr explorer to checkout the branch, you should only give `bzr://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk` as the URL in the checkout dialog.

Otherwise, running `bzr co bzr://bzr.mozilla.org/bugzilla/trunk bugzilla` from a console window should work.